# Retrieving data across two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to MySQL and need to get data from a column where the id in another column of the same table matches the id in a second table and I'm not sure how to go about it.

I haven't tried anything yet as I'm too new to go about answering my own question, sorry.

So my first table looks like this

```
userid    questionid    score
-----------------------------
1         1             5
1         2             4
1         3             7
1         4             10
1         4             6
```

And my 2nd table looks like this

```
otherfields    userid
---------------------
blah           1
blah 2         2
etc            3
you            4
get            5
the            6
idea           7
```

So what I need to do is select all the scores from table 1 where userid of table 1 matches the user id of table 2.

Comment: Please share your desired results from the SQL you are wanting to write. "Where the userid matches the userid of table2" isn't very clear. Do you want the sum of the scores? What does "Match" mean here? Desired results would make this much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to sum up the score for each user?
Then something like this could help:

```
SELECT t2.userid, t2.otherfields, SUM(t1.score) AS sum_score
FROM first_table t1
LEFT JOIN second_table t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
GROUP BY t2.userid
```

First, you join the two tables together based on `userid` which is the same over both tables. Then you `GROUP` all rows which belong to the same user (e.g. question 1-5 for user 1) together and finally you `SUM` up the scores of each row of a group.